# How do I ensure that the CSI ext4 filesystem in GCP is created and mounted using the discard option for smaller snapshots

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, container-storage-interface

The `discard` option is [required to avoid taking snapshots of data that is not used by the filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting).

However, creating a standard, documented, storageclass like the following does not use this option.  How can I modify the storage class so that it uses `discard`?

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```